# If (break == 1) break; is not working

Tags: c, if-statement, break

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {
    int i;
    for( i = 0; i< 10 ; i++ ) {
        printf("test1 &d", i);
        if (i == 2)
            break;
    }
    if (break == 1) //line 10
        printf("test2 %d", i);

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

This code returns two errors. First is syntax error break at line 10. Second is expected an expression at line 10.

edit: I didnt use break as a variable. I remember using break for this purpose few years ago and i remember it used to work. So i asked to learn if it worked back then because i was using a different compiler or something.

Comment: Actually, the errors are all right. What's the problem?

Comment: What do you think `break == 1` means?

Comment: `break` is not a variable, you cannot compare it. It is an instruction.

Comment: I think the c standard uses the terminology of "statement".

Comment: "I didnt use break as a variable. I tried to do this: If the break in for was executed, break here too." Where did you get the idea that this ought to work?

Comment: @Ben i just remember using this few years ago. I wanted to know if this was a true or false idea. Thats why i asked.

Comment: You'll need to give more details about this mysterious memory of yours.  Like: what version of what compiler were you using, and can you reproduce the expected behaviour with a small test program.  Anyway, regardless of what you remember, NOW you cannot do that [any more]; it's a syntax error.  So if you can't expand on that memory, you'll just have to chalk it down to one of life's little mysteries.  Certainly nobody here will be able to explain why it worked before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`break` is a keyword and can't be used as a variable.

From [section 6.8.6.3 of the C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf):

> 1  A break statement shall appear only in or as a switch body or loop body.
>
> 2 A break statement terminates execution of the smallest enclosing switch
>   or iteration statement.

If you want to detect whether or not you broke out of the `for` loop, you need a separate variable for that:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {
    int i, breakout = 0;
    for( i = 0; i< 10 ; i++ ) {
        printf("test1 &d", i);
        if (i == 2) {
            breakout = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (breakout == 1) //line 10
        printf("test2 %d", i);

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In the example code, if `i` is less than 10 the loop ended via the `break` statement.

Comment: @dbush There is no point of using one more extra variable "breakout".

Comment: i know how to do this with breakout. i remember using break for this purpose. thats why i asked.

Comment: @AnılErtürk The `break` keyword can only be used as a statement by itself to get out of a `for`, `while`, or `switch`.  The `if (break == 1)` syntax you were trying to use is invalid and does not work.

Comment: @AnılErtürk See my edit regarding the relevant link from the standard.

Answer (score 4):

The `break` is not a variable, you cannot compare it. It is an instruction. If you want to know if the loop exited prematurely, instead of

```
if (break == 1)
```

you could use

```
if (i < 10)
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot compare 'break' with an integer. Break is a statement that makes you leave the current loop.
I am not sure what your intent is? What are you trying to do?

For more information in break:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/37zc9d2w.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The `break` statement is not a function, therefore it does not return a value when the statement is used. This means that the comparison 'break ==1` is invalid and can not be tested.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that you're using 'break' as a variable, and it's a reserved word; You can't treat it as a variable.

If what you are trying to accomplish is to do something if and only if the for-loop broke out, you could just invoke printf before the break statement and it would work just fine.